# How can I select a default option with Symfony formbuilder when using query_builder?

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

With my formBuilder I am building a choice field:

```
$options = [
              'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
              'data' => '2',
              'mapped' => false,
              'label' => $label,
              'data_class' => null,
            ];

if ($type == 'choice') {

              $options['attr'] = array('class' => 'form-control select2');
              $options['class'] = 'App\Entity\Options';
              $options['choice_label'] = 'name';
              $options['query_builder'] = function (EntityRepository $er) use ($fieldId) {
                   return $er->createQueryBuilder('f')
                          ->leftJoin('f.fields', 'fi')
                          ->where(":id MEMBER OF f.fields")
                          ->setParameter(':id', $fieldId);
              };
              $options['data'] = '2';


   $formBuilder->add($id, ChoiceType::class, $options);
}
```

It works well, a choice field is created with all my options. The problem is, that I want the default selected option to be `2`.

And this doesn't work. Always the first option is selected. So the default selected option is always `green`. But I need it to be `blue`. This is selectbox, that is created:

```
<select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="1">green</option>
    <option value="2">blue</option>        
    <option value="3">red</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do not add "oop" to all of your questions. This question is not about "oop".

Comment: `$formBuilder->add..` is not oop?

Comment: The question is not related to object oriented programming. It's about the use of a particular Symfony component. There were no OOP principles involved in answering the question.

Comment: @yivi Ah ok, I understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting data to a literal. Set it to an object reference:

```
$options['data'] = $entityManager->getReference(YourEntity::class, 2);
```